# How to set combo box value to array value when combo box is not uniquely identified?

Tags: java, javafx, combobox, fxml

I have a key which I want to set to the value of each of 26 combo boxes which I have generated using a loop, hence do not have a fx:id which I can call to set the value with.

I have an GUI which either contains 26 combo boxes or a spinner depending on the value of a particular other combo box. These are automatically generated by an enumerator which loads them into a blank space on my GUI (I have set up the 26 combo boxes to be generated by me coding 1 of them (they all have the same values inside) and using a loop to generate 26 of them). 
For the 26 combo boxes, I have a char array[26] which I want to set each combo box to a different value in the array, but since they have been generated using a loop, I can't seem to set a unique fx:id to each combo box so that I could call them to set the values. 
I think I need to bind them somehow to the array, but I'm very new to javafx/fxml so I don't know how to do this.

This generates the combo boxes:

```
private SubstitutionKey key;

public SubstitutionKeyEditorView(SubstitutionKey key) {
    this.key = key;
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("SubstitutionKeyEditor.fxml"));
    loader.setController(this);
    loader.setRoot(this);
    try {
        loader.load();
        for (char x = 'A'; x <= 'Z'; x++) {
            getChildren().add(new LetterSelectorView(String.valueOf(x), this)); //add 26 letter selectors (26 combo boxes)
        }
    } catch (IOException exc) {
        throw new RuntimeException(exc);
    }
}
```

The SubstitutionKeyEditor.fxml only sets the type to flowPane so they display nicely.

This is the letterSelectorView:

```
@FXML
private Label letterLabel;
@FXML
private ComboBox letterSelection;

public LetterSelectorView(String letter, LetterChangedListener listener) {
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("LetterSelector.fxml"));
    //add the text and combo box to the place being loaded into
    loader.setController(this);
    loader.setRoot(this);
    try {
        loader.load();
        letterLabel.setText(letter); //give the label the correct letter
        letterSelection.getItems().add(" "); //add blank
        for (char x = 'A'; x <= 'Z'; x++) {
            letterSelection.getItems().add(String.valueOf(x)); //add all the letters to each combo box
        }
        letterSelection.valueProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> listener.letterChanged(letter, (String) newValue));
        //if value of combo box changes, rerun cipher
    } catch (IOException exc) {
        throw new RuntimeException(exc);
    }
}
```

I am trying to do all this from another controller CipherController (which is where the substitutionKeyEditorView is generated into). In here I have a char array letters[26] which I want to set the value of each combo box generated by the substitutionKeyEditorView to a value of a specific index in this array.

I hope that makes sense!

Comment: Use node.setUserData().

Comment: @Sedrick Sorry for possibly being stupid, but where should I use it? In the controller for the cipher GUI or when I'm setting up the comboboxes?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem (and keep it minimal: no need for 26 combos, 2 or at most 3 are enough :)

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you can probably get around your problem just using a `List` and the `List` index. Not 100% sure because your question is missing the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

If you need to set the `UserData`, I think it should be done when creating the `ComboBox`.

Example:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author blj0011
 */
public class JavaFXApplication329 extends Application
{

    ComboBox<String> mainComboBox = new ComboBox();
    List<ComboBox<String>> comboBoxes = new ArrayList();
    String[] data = "ABCDE".split("");
    String[] value = "01234".split("");

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage)
    {
        mainComboBox.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(value));
        mainComboBox.setValue("0");

        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            ComboBox<String> tempComboBox = new ComboBox<>(FXCollections.observableArrayList(data));
            tempComboBox.setUserData("ComboBox" + i);//If you need to set the UserData or you can just use the List index
            tempComboBox.setValue(data[i]);
            comboBoxes.add(tempComboBox);
        }

        mainComboBox.getSelectionModel().selectedIndexProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                String tempValue = data[(newValue.intValue() + i) % 5];
                comboBoxes.get(i).setValue(tempValue);
            }
        });

        VBox vBox = new VBox(mainComboBox);
        vBox.getChildren().addAll(comboBoxes);

        StackPane root = new StackPane(vBox);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! In it's current form it isn't possible to set the values when they are being set up, however you have given me an idea of how I could work it so that I re-set it up when I want to load the data and use the key every time to do this. I will investigate this in more detail tomorrow as a possibility. Thanks once again!